# How to extract output policy from contextual bandit in vowpal wabbit?

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I am running this [example](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Contextual-Bandit-Example) for contextual bandit, on example data as theirs:

```
1:2:0.4 | a c  
3:0.5:0.2 | b d  
4:1.2:0.5 | a b c  
2:1:0.3 | b c  
3:1.5:0.7 | a d
```

with command as their suggestions:

`vw -d train.dat --cb 4 --cb_type dr -f traindModel`

and I wonder how to extract the policy from this command and how to interpret it then?

And then I go

```
vw -d train.dat --invert_hash traindModel
```

and recieve such output

```
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
using no cache
Reading datafile = ../r-mkosinski/train.dat
num sources = 1
average    since         example     example  current  current  current
loss       last          counter      weight    label  predict features
1.000000   1.000000          1      1.0     1.0000   0.0000        3
4.439352   7.878704          2      2.0     3.0000   0.1931        3
4.457758   4.476164          4      4.0     2.0000   1.4285        3

finished run
number of examples per pass = 5
passes used = 1
weighted example sum = 5
weighted label sum = 13
average loss = 4.14973
best constant = 2.6
total feature number = 16
```

How to interpet those results? How to extract policy?

I also tried this type of command:

```
vw -d train.dat --cb 4 --cb_type dr  --invert_hash p2222.txt
```

and got the following result:

```
Version 7.8.0
Min label:0.000000
Max label:5.000000
bits:18
0 pairs: 
0 triples: 
lda:0
0 ngram: 
0 skip: 
options: --cb 4 --cb_type dr --csoaa 4
:0
 ^a:108232:0.263395
 ^a:108233:-0.028344
 ^a:108234:0.140435
 ^a:108235:0.215673
 ^a:108236:0.234253
 ^a:108238:0.203977
 ^a:108239:0.182416
 ^b:129036:-0.061075
 ^b:129037:0.242713
 ^b:129038:0.229821
 ^b:129039:0.206961
 ^b:129041:0.185534
 ^b:129042:0.137167
 ^b:129043:0.182416
 ^c:219516:0.264300
 ^c:219517:0.242713
 ^c:219518:-0.158527
 ^c:219519:0.206961
 ^c:219520:0.234253
 ^c:219521:0.185534
 ^c:219523:0.182416
 ^d:20940:-0.058402
 ^d:20941:-0.028344
 ^d:20942:0.372860
 ^d:20943:-0.056001
 ^d:20946:0.326036
Constant:202096:0.263742
Constant:202097:0.242226
Constant:202098:0.358272
Constant:202099:0.205581
Constant:202100:0.234253
Constant:202101:0.185534
Constant:202102:0.326036
Constant:202103:0.182416
```

Why there are only 5 record for `d` in output, and 7 for `c`,`b`,`a`? Does it correspond to that features `c`,`b`,`a` occured in data 3 times and `d` only 2 times? There are also 8 constant rows.. to what do they correspond?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> vw -d train.dat --invert_hash traindModel

No contextual bandit is specified here, so vw does a simple linear regression.

> How to interpet those results?

See https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Tutorial#vws-diagnostic-information

> There are also 8 constant rows.. to what do they correspond?

Contextual bandit in VW is implemented using a *reduction* to (in this case) cost-sensitive one-against-all multiclass classification. And the csoaa is in turn implemented as a reduction to a linear regression. When using `--csoaa 4`, each "original feature" is combined with all possible output *labels* (or *actions* in case of contextual bandit), so instead of one original feature, there are four features (unfortunately, they have the same name in --invert_hash output, so you cannot be sure which label corresponds to which feature, but they have different hashes, so you see these are different features).

I think contextual bandit also needs to multiply the number of features, but I am not sure what is the multiplication factor for a given --cb_type. From the example, we see it is at least 2, because there are up to 8 features with the same name, while `--csoaa 4` is responsible only for the factor of 4.

> Why there are only 5 record for d in output, and 7 for c,b,a?

Features with zero weight are not stored in the model.

> Does it correspond to that features c,b,a occured in data 3 times and d only 2 times?

Somehow yes, but not directly.  As explained above, the features in --invert_hash correspond to feature-label combinations (i.e. combination of the original feature and the output label=action). If a given example is not predicted correctly (during online learning), the feature-correct_label weight will be increased and the feature-predicted_label weight will be decreased (this is the effect of one-against-all reduction). So if a given feature-label combination is never seen in the training data, it is likely that its weight will remain zero (it will be never increased nor decreased).

Comment: See also https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/issues/1566#issuecomment-413844680